# Why can I not direct-initialize a private member variable in the class definition

Tags: c++

Let's suppose I have the following code:

```
class A
{
    public:
        A(int Val)
        {
            _val = Val;
        }
        virtual ~A() = default;

    private:
        int _val = 0;
};

class B
{
    public:
        B() = default;
        virtual ~B() = default;

    private:
        A _a(3); // Error: expected identifier before numeric constant
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

when I try to direct-initialize "A _a(3);" I will get the following error from the compiler: 
"xpected identifier before numeric constant"
What is wrong about it?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `A _a(3);` problem is that this looks like declaration of method, but instead a type value is used.

Comment: Follow reading _"Most Vexing Parse"_ nearest SO link I can find (not an exact duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use `{}` syntax:

```
class B
{
public:
    B() = default;
    virtual ~B() = default;

private:
    A _a{ 3 };
};
```

or  use `=`:

```
class B
{
public:
    B() = default;
    virtual ~B() = default;

private:
    A _a = A(3);
};
```

parenthesis is not allowed to avoid vexing parse.

Answer (score 3):

```
A _a(3);
```

C++ compiler interprets above line as a function _a() which returns a type A.

As pointed out by @Jarod42 `A _a{3};` will work fine.